# How can I change the price format used in email templates?

Tags: orocommerce

I need to send an email notification when a new Order is received and I need the price to be formatted in a different way than the rest of the site.

Is there a way to send parameters to oro_format_price?

I tried to replace oro_format_price with a simple number_format but it didn't work...

Thanks

Edit:

Digging around the code ([Here](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/CurrencyBundle/Twig/CurrencyExtension.php) and [here](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/LocaleBundle/Resources/doc/reference/number-formatting.md#oro_format_currency)) I found there are options to be passed to oro_format_price filter so I put this code in my email template:

```
{{ item.price.value|oro_format_price({symbols: {decimal_separator_symbol: '.', grouping_separator: '' }}) }}
```

Which is not showing me any error, but I'm not getting any email either :(

I'm using version 3.1.17 BTW

Edit 2:

I've checked again and I found somethings I had written wrong, my current version looks like this:

```
{{ item.price|oro_format_price({symbols: {decimal_separator_symbol: '.', grouping_separator_symbol: '', monetary_grouping_separator_symbol: '', currency_symbol:'' }}) }}
```

Now the email is sent but the format is not changed :(

Edit 3:

I changed it again to try and use a simpler way:

```
{{ item.price.value|number_format(2, '.','') }}
```

and found these errors in the log:

```
app.ERROR: An error occurred while processing notification {"exception":"[object] (Oro\\Bundle\\EmailBundle\\Exception\\EmailTemplateCompilationException(code: 0): Could not found one email template with \"order_confirmation_test\" name for \"Oro\\Bundle\\OrderBundle\\Entity\\Order\" entity at /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/EmailBundle/Provider/EmailTemplateContentProvider.php:71)"} []

 app.ERROR: An error occurred while sending "Oro\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Event\Handler\TemplateEmailNotificationAdapter" notification with email template "order_confirmation_test" for "Oro\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\Order" entity {"exception":"[object] (Oro\\Bundle\\NotificationBundle\\Exception\\NotificationSendException(code: 0): Could not send notification of type \"Oro\\Bundle\\NotificationBundle\\Event\\Handler\\TemplateEmailNotificationAdapter\" for email template \"order_confirmation_test\" for \"Oro\\Bundle\\OrderBundle\\Entity\\Order\" entity at /usr/share/nginx/html/oroapp/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/NotificationBundle/Manager/EmailNotificationManager.php:125)"} []
```

I tried to output the same through a regular template (outside of an email I mean) and it worked ok.

Looking at php error_log file I found this message:

```
"NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Notice:  Calling "getvalue" method on a "Oro\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\Entity\Price" object is not allowed in ...
```

I checked the class Oro\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\Entity\Price and the getValue method is public so I don't understand why this is failing :(

Answer (score 0):

Email templates have a separate twig rendering engine with a limited list of available functions. This is achieved using the [sandbox extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#sandbox-extension).

To expose a function to the email rendering engine you can use `Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AbstractTwigSandboxConfigurationPass`.

For example, see an existing implementation, like `\Oro\Bundle\PaymentBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TwigSandboxConfigurationPass`